# Does spacetime topology have importance in physics?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology

Generally in textbooks they represent spacetime as $(M,\nabla,g,t)$
where $M$ is a Lorentzian manifold,$\nabla$ a torsion-free connection,$g$ a metric and $t$ a time orientation.
But they do not talk of topology. My question is does the topology of spacetime have importance in physics?

Comment: As with any manifold the open sets defined by the topology are used in defining charts.

Comment: Usually $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection associated to $g$. However, the topology is included in the definition of the smooth manifold $M$.

Comment: The second Stiefel-Whitney class has to vanish so one can define spinors on the manifold. And obviously this last has to be orientable.

Comment: You cannot meaningfully define a smooth manifold without looking at the topology. As an example it $M$ needs to be second-countable which is a topological property.

Comment: More on the [topology of spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology+spacetime).

Comment: The topology can be defined by the metric $g$ that you have mentioned giving the metric topolgy. Topology can have important consequences in physics as it describes the global structure. For example, a spacetime can be closed or open which can have different physical importatnce.

Comment: The rigorous way to define black hole solutions is by means of non trivial spacetime topology. Most of the important objects that black hole physics introduce are "global" concepts; singularities and horizons are good examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

Spacetime topology certainly has importance in physics.

In condensed matter physics, topological phases of matter are systems which are [sensitive to spacetime topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_degeneracy#:%7E:text=In%20quantum%20many%2Dbody%20physics,lifted%20by%20any%20local%20perturbations.). Many of the interesting ones are two dimensional, so they can in principle be fabricated into interesting surfaces in a lab. Alternatively, through clever tuning of non-local interactions, physics on non-trivial 3-manifolds can be engineered as well.

In cosmology there is the question of the topology of the universe. It was once [hypothesized](https://www.ams.org/notices/200406/fea-weeks.pdf) that the universe is a Poincare homology sphere. Wormholes give the universe interesting topology, but that topology is usually hidden behind  an event horizon. This general phenomenon is known as cosmic censorship, and is an active area of study.

Comment: Aren't there also particle models that depend on non-trivial topologies?

Comment: @S.McGrew What do you have in mind?

Comment: For example, the electron model proposed by Hestenes: https://vixra.org/pdf/1408.0203v2.pdf.